# why git status shows "working directory clean" even after I add a new file

Tags: git, git-status, git-untracked

```
$ git --version
git version 2.5.3

$ git branch
* feature/branchABC

$ git status -b branchABC
On branch feature/branchABC
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/branchABC'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ echo "abc" > abc.cpp

$ git status -b branchABC
On branch feature/branchABC
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/branchABC'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Question> After I add a new file `abc.cpp` in the current folder, why I still see the message 'working directory clean` in git?

Thank you

--Update One--

```
$ git status
On branch feature/branchABC
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/feature/branchABC'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        abc.cpp

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Comment: What does plain ol' `git status` give you?  Y'know, without the `-b` argument?

Comment: the `git status` does show up the untracked file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the command `git status` doesn't require an argument. The argument `branchABC` that you provided is interpreted by `git-status` as a path. So git checks the status of a file or directory named `branchABC`. Solution: just use one of the following commands:

```
git status
git status -b
```

in the `git-status` man page: `git status [<options>...] [--] [<pathspec>...]`, and since `branchABC` is not a valid option; it is interpreted as `pathspec`. I agree that maybe git could have put a warning that there is nothing matching the path `branchABC`...

I tested this locally.

```
$ git status
# On branch test
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       spec/a
#       src/a

$ git status src
# On branch test
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       src/a

$ git status non-existing-path
# On branch test
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Answer (score -2):

Actually `abc.cpp` is a new file. Since it is not commited in to git. Any change you made is tracked only as a new file.

Once you add the file and commit, git will keep track the changes.

So add the file using

```
git add abc.cpp

or

git add .
```

So that git will keep track the changes of the file `abc.cpp`.
You can try an online excercise for all basic commands here

> https://try.github.io

Comment: That does not answer his question: normally an untracked file should show up (if it is not in gitignore), and it doesn't... proof is his edited question: using only git status; the file shows up...

Comment: @ChrisMaes It shows the file as `untracked` as you can see his updated answer. Hope you can see as the file as untracked

Comment: in the update of his question it shows up as untracked, allright. But his question is not "why does this file show up untracked", but `why I still see the message 'working directory clean' in git?`

Comment: your information is not wrong, but it just isn't the answer to this question.

Comment: @ChrisMaes why I still see the message 'working directory clean' in git?` This what i have answered. Git is not tracking the newly created file since is not added. You can check it here . you just answered in a complex instead of simple words http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/69178/what-is-the-benefit-of-gits-two-stage-commit-process-staging

Comment: You say you still see the message "working directory clean'; which command are you using? If you just use `git status`, as explained in my answer above, then you should see the untracked file (if you have one, that is).